# How to read simple xml file with lxml with iso-8859-1 encoding using child.text function

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, iso-8859-1

I have xml files with follwing simple structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<DICTIONARY>
    <Tag1>
        Übung1 Übersetzung1
        Übung2 Übersetzung2
        Übung3 Übersetzung3
        Übung4 Übersetzung4
        Übung5 Übersetzung5
    </Tag1>
    <Tag2>
        Übung6 Übersetzung6
        Übung7 Übersetzung7
        Übung8 Übersetzung8
        Übung9 Übersetzung9
        Übung10 Übersetzung10
    </Tag2>
</DICTIONARY>
```

I wanted to read these files with lxml because of its simplicity. I used  child.text to read the text parts, but the encoding seems not be passed to the output string. See code and ouput below.

I already used codecs to read the file with iso-8859-1, but it didn't change anything.

```py
from lxml import etree
import codecs

def read_xml(): 
    taglist=[]
    new_dicts=[]
    with codecs.open("A:/test/test.txt", 'r', 
                     encoding='iso-8859-1') as xmlfile:
        try:
            tree=etree.parse(xmlfile)
            loaded=True
            print ("XML-encoding: ",tree.docinfo.encoding)
        except:
            loaded=False
            print ("""No dictionary loaded or xml structure is missing! Please try again!""")


    if loaded:

        root = tree.getroot()

        for child in root:
            new_dict={}
            tagname=child.tag
            taglist.append(tagname)

            print ("Loading dictionary for tag: ",
                   tagname)
            allstrings= child.text                
            allstrings=allstrings.split("\n")

            for line in allstrings:
                if line!=" " and line!="":
                    line=line.split("\t")
                    if line[0]!="" and line[1]!="":
                        enc_line0=line[0]
                        enc_line1=line[1]
                        new_dict.update({enc_line0:enc_line1})
            new_dicts.append(new_dict)

    return taglist, new_dicts
print (read_xml())
```

**Output:**

```
XML-encoding:  iso-8859-1
Loading dictionary for tag:  Tag1
Loading dictionary for tag:  Tag2
(['Tag1', 'Tag2'], [{'Ã\x9cbung1': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung1', 'Ã\x9cbung2': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung2', 'Ã\x9cbung3': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung3', 'Ã\x9cbung4': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung4', 'Ã\x9cbung5': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung5'}, {'Ã\x9cbung6': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung6', 'Ã\x9cbung7': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung7', 'Ã\x9cbung8': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung8', 'Ã\x9cbung9': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung9', 'Ã\x9cbung10': 'Ã\x9cbersetzung10'}])
```

Whereas, I expected to get an ouput in the same way as with command print ("Übung"), for example. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lxml works with binary files. Try to change

```
with codecs.open("A:/test/test.txt", 'r', 
                 encoding='iso-8859-1') as xmlfile:
```

to

```
with codecs.open("A:/test/test.txt", 'rb', 
                 encoding='iso-8859-1') as xmlfile:
```

Comment: Ok, opening file with encoding-statement does not work again even with reading as binary, whereas opening without encoding-statement works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not find a proper solution, but by converting all stuff in UTF-8, I had no problems with further steps - such as comparing words with umlaut from dictionary and other strings.